# uneven growth rate of progression in animation

Tags: python, animation, kivy

Look at flowing code:

```
from kivy.app           import App;
from kivy.uix.widget    import Widget;
from kivy.animation     import Animation;
from kivy.uix.button    import Button;
from time               import time;
import json;

but = Button();
anim = Animation(size_hint = (.75 , .75), duration = 1);
anim += Animation(size_hint = (.5 , .5), duration = 1);
anim += Animation(size_hint = (.25 , .25), duration = 1);
anim += Animation(size_hint = (.0 , .0), duration = 1);

progress_array = [];
time_array = [];

start_time = time();

def progr_fun(*args):
    global time_array, progress_array;
    time_array.append((time() - start_time));
    print((time() - start_time));
    progress_array.append(args[2]);
    print(args[2]);
    

anim.bind(on_progress = progr_fun);

anim.start(but);

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return but;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run();

f_obj = open('hello', 'w');
json.dump([progress_array, time_array], f_obj);
f_obj.close();
```

Its program, that makes easy animation for button. Animation consists of several parts (its important). There is callback on_progress that collects time data and progression. This data saved at the end of program.
I'm using another script to build plot by time and progression and get something like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs1Ak.png)

As you can see in different parts of animation progression growing unevenly.
Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "unevenly"?

Comment: Sorry about my English. I talk about **different speed** of growth of progression, in different parts of animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is odd behavior, but I think the cause is a different time interval used to step through the different parts of the animation. I believe those intervals, while changing for the different phases, are within the resolution of the kivy clock.

I'm not sure why those intervals change. I believe that is done in the C-code underneath the kivy Clock.

The `+` operator for `Animation` objects produces a `Sequence` subclass of `Animation`, and that seems to trigger the difference. A workaround is to construct your own sequence, Something like this:

```
    self.anim1 = Animation(size_hint=(.75, .75))
    self.anim2 = Animation(size_hint=(.5, .5))
    self.anim3 = Animation(size_hint=(.25, .25))
    self.anim4 = Animation(size_hint=(.0, .0))

    self.anim1.bind(on_progress=self.progr_fun, on_complete=self.start2)
    self.anim2.bind(on_progress=self.progr_fun, on_complete=self.start3)
    self.anim3.bind(on_progress=self.progr_fun, on_complete=self.start4)
    self.anim4.bind(on_progress=self.progr_fun)
    self.anim1.start(self.but)

def start2(self, *args):
    self.anim2.start(self.but)

def start3(self, *args):
    self.anim3.start(self.but)

def start4(self, *args):
    self.anim4.start(self.but)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible solution - make your own progress rate using time.time(). Its can looks like that:

```
but = Button();
anim = Animation(size_hint = (.75 , .75), duration = 1);
anim += Animation(size_hint = (.5 , .5), duration = 1);
anim += Animation(size_hint = (.25 , .25), duration = 1);
anim += Animation(size_hint = (.0 , .0), duration = 1);


def start_fun(*args):
    global start_time;
    start_time = time();

def progr_fun(*args):
    global time_array, progress_array, start_time , anim;
    my_progress = (time() - start_time) / anim.duration;
    print(my_progress);
    
anim.bind(  on_progress = progr_fun,
            on_start = start_fun);

anim.start(but);
```

But this variant not so accurate. You can get something like that at the end of animation:

1.0635101795196533
1.0677716732025146
1.0720353722572327